# Equivalent solutions of the integral of $\tan^3x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The solution I got is $$\frac{\tan^2x}{2}+\ln|\cos x|+C$$
and the answer from my textbook is $$\frac{\ln|\cos^2 x|}{2}+\frac{1}{2\cos(2x)}$$
Apparently these are supposed to be equivalent, but I don't understand how.

Comment: Graphing them in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qiob5y4z57), they seem to not be equivalent; otherwise, their difference would be a constant, but it's not.

Comment: What makes constant as multiplier of logarithm and play with trigonometric one law and cosine of double

Comment: There results are not equal as the zeros of $\cos x$ and $\cos(2x)$ are different. Perhaps the answer in the texbook contains $\cos^{-2}x$ in place of $\cos^{-1}(2x)$ ?

Comment: By the way I am surprised that textbook gives $\ln|\cos^2x|$ as the absolute value is redundant. Your solution is correct. I guess you got it by $(\tan^2x+1)\tan x-\tan x.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{\log |\cos^2 x|}{2} = \frac{2 \log |\cos x|}{2} = \log |\cos x|,$$ so the only difference between the two functions, up to some constant of integration, is $\tan^2 x$ and $\sec 2x$.  Assume that there exists some $x$ such that $$h(x) = \tan^2 x - \sec 2x + C(x) = 0$$ for some piecewise constant function $C(x)$ satisfying $C'(x) = 0$ for almost all $x$.  This would imply
$$h'(x) = 2 \sec^2 x \tan x - 2 \sec 2x \tan 2x = 0$$
for almost all $x$ in the domain of $h$.  But this is false; e.g., $h'(\pi/3) = 4 \sqrt{3}$.  So we know that one of these cannot be correct.  Taking the derivative of each, we easily see that the correct one is
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log |\cos x| + \frac{\tan^2 x}{2} \right] = -\tan x + \sec^2 \tan x = \tan x (-1 + \sec^2 x) = \tan x (\tan^2 x) = \tan^3 x.$$

Comment: Are you sure that  the absolute value is necessary in the expression$|\cos^2x|$ ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I am only repeating the expression that was provided in the question.  I'm not making any claims about the necessity of the way it was written.